# how to make py.test --cov skip virtualenv directory

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, pytest, test-coverage

Should I care how my tests cover the external libraries I'm using in my project ?

The py.test --cov displays how all files are covered, including ones in my virtualenv directory. How can I make the output show only the coverage of the modules I've written ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should add your module's name to the `--cov` command line option, for example form `pytest-cov` documentation:

```
py.test --cov=myproj tests/
```

This restrict the coverage to the module `myproj` and all its sub-modules.

Answer (score 62):

In the root of your project, create file `.coveragerc` containing:

```
[run]
omit = path_to_libs_to_omit/*
```

Depending on your setup, you might need to add `--cov-config=path/to/.coveragerc` as option to the py.test command.

There are more options you can use [to configure coverage](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html).

Comment: worth mentioning that you can have multiple paths by using a comma separated list ```[run]
omit = path_to_libs_to_omit/**,path_to_other_libs_to_omit/** ```

Comment: you can also define multiple paths for `omit` as one path per line (great if you have a lot to exclude).

Comment: Alternately, add an entry to your tox.ini `[coverage:run] omit = path_to_libs_to_omit/*` as documented at https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html

Answer (score 22):

@alexamici answer is the correct one for virtualenvs, but for completeness, adding `pyproject.toml` (suggested config file for python projects) set up:

```
[tool.coverage.run]
omit = [
    "file/to/exclude.py",
    "other/file.py",
    "some/path/*"
    ]
```

Comment: If you are working with reporting only, this might not work, instead
`[tool.coverage.report]`
Rest will be the same.

Answer (score 4):

one-liner，

```sh
echo -e "[run]\nomit = venv/*" > .coveragerc && pytest -v --cov
```

Pretty handy if you use this in CI or if you don't want to add `.coveragerc` to your git repo just because of 'venv'.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I managed to do it:
`pytest.py`

```
[pytest]
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
addopts = -v -p no:warnings --nomigrations --cov=. --no-cov-on-fail
```

`coveragerc`

```
[run]
omit = venv/*
```